# How to keep button at reload web?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 button, but I made this 1 display button maybe like same toggle button.
This program will be implement to CI for insert data(as input booking) and update data(as cancel just update column is_booking = 0).
[This example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWHBW.png).

So, I want this button not change at refresh web or reload. Help me please :).

```js
function toggle1(){
document.getElementById("input2").removeAttribute("class");
var x = document.getElementById("input1");
var y = document.getElementById("input2");
x.style.display = "none";
y.style.display = "flex";
}

function toggle2(){
var x = document.getElementById("input1");
var y = document.getElementById("input2");
x.style.display = "flex";
y.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.hidden{ visibility: hidden;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Button 2 in 1</h2>

<button type="submit" id="input1" onclick="toggle1()">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" id="input2" class="hidden pucek" onclick='toggle2()'>Button 2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need either localStorage or server-sided scripting/programming. Plenty o duplicates and tutorials here on SO or the web. Also, you properly want to look into `classList.toggle()` which would cut down your JS code by at least 50%. Does not change the fact that you need `localStorage` or Server-sided scripting to store the currently active button.

Comment: Thanks for suggest. I will try to add classList.toggle(). Once, Thanks for reply my post